# laravel 5.1 and angular 2.1

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.1 and Angular JS 2.1. But my view are not catching angular directives.

I have already gone through all the alternatives provided on stackoverflow, but could not find a solution, please suggest :-

Here is the code of ex10.blade.php

```
<html ng-app="nameApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', []);
      nameApp.controller('NameCtrl', function($scope){
         $scope.firstName = 'Manish';
         $scope.lastName = 'Sijaria';       
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
    First name: <input  ng-model="firstName" type="text"> </input>
    </br>
    Last name: <input  ng-model="lastName" type="text">  </input>
    </br>
    Hello @{{ firstName }}  @{{ lastName }}    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're importing angular 2.0 but the angular markup you have is for angular 1.x. Angular 2 is a significant departure from the way angular 1.x works and is not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Angular 1.x markup while importing Angular 2.x js. Try changing your Angular.js version.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

See a [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6kJbPRyJSqKeLc7NFAqF?p=preview).

Comment: yes, it worked with 1.5.8 version of angular. The code samples of screencast on URL https://github.com/curran/screencasts/tree/gh-pages/introToAngular  are outdated.   Can somebody provide links to Angular 2.0  code samples where it can be tried.

Comment: @user3903517 The [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) have a good QuickStart with working samples

Answer (score 0):

You're importing Angular 2.0beta but the code that you posted is actually Angular 1.x. Angular 2 is a major overhaul of Angular and the markup is very different so you cannot use Angular 1 markup with angular 2.

The easy fix here is to import angular 1.5 instead of importing angular 2.0 beta. That should make this code work.

Angular 2 is getting really close to release so you should be able to use it without too much trouble if you really want to. Although You will have to update all your markup, and JS to the new angular syntax.